# Summing up certain data from nested dictionaries python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

So I have the following code

```
Filme = {'1': {'Titel': 'Titanic', 'Jahr': 1997, 'Wertung': 8, 'Preis': 30,
                               'Schauspielern': ["Adam Sandler", 'b', 'c']},
         '2': {'Titel': 'Pulp Fiction', 'Jahr': 1994, 'Wertung': 9, 'Preis': 40, 'Schauspielern': ['']},
         '3': {'Titel': 'Wings of Desire', 'Jahr': 1987, 'Wertung': 8, 'Preis': 40,
                               'Schauspielern': ['']},
         '4': {'Titel': 'London Has Fallen', 'Jahr': 2016, 'Wertung': 6, 'Preis': 20,
                               'Schauspielern': ['']},
         '5': {'Titel': 'Avatar', 'Jahr': 2009, 'Wertung': 8, 'Preis': 35, 'Schauspielern': ['']},
         '6': {'Titel': 'The Devil Wears Prada', 'Jahr': 2006, 'Wertung': 7, 'Preis': 20,
                               'Schauspielern': ['']},
         '7': {'Titel': 'Submarine', 'Jahr': 2010, 'Wertung': 7, 'Preis': 20, 'Schauspielern': ['']},
         '8': {'Titel': 'About Time', 'Jahr': 2013, 'Wertung': 8, 'Preis': 37, 'Schauspielern': ['']},
         '9': {'Titel': 'Love, Rosie', 'Jahr': 2014, 'Wertung': 7, 'Preis': 25, 'Schauspielern': ['']},
         '10': {'Titel': 'Me Before You', 'Jahr': 2016, 'Wertung': 9, 'Preis': 45,'Schauspielern': ['']}
         }
```

The task I have to do is to calculate the total price (the variable used is "Preis") I'd have by choosing different movies. For example, if I choose movies 1, 4, and 8, the output should be 87 (30 + 20 + 37)
Is there anyway I can do this? Thanks

Comment: How do you choose the movies?

Comment: Using Pandas makes this kind of problems easy to solve. Here is a quick tutorial: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

Comment: @grovina basically by picking up the index numbers. For now, I have the idea in my head, but can't think of a way to apply it

Comment: You said you have an "idea in your head, but can't think of a way to apply it", that maybe because in python we don't apply "ideas", we apply functions.

Comment: @JoeT.Boka I'm pretty much a beginner in using Python. So no need for rude comments, thank you

Comment: My comment wasn't meant to be a rude. In SO you should post what you've tried so far to solve the problem. Show your code and let us know where you're stuck. I didn't down-vote you, but whoever did, I am sure that's the reason they did it. So, if you keep posting questions without showing some sort of an attempt to solve the problem, you will be getting a lot of down-votes. That's my message. It's not rude...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this as well:

```
movies = [1,4,8]

def getTotalMoney(movies, Filme):
  return sum(Filme.get(str(i)).get("Preis") for i in movies)

print(getTotalMoney(movies, Filme))
```

The result is:

```
87
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t= ['1','4','8']
print reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, map(lambda x: Filme[x]['Preis'], t), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have the movie numbers in a list (you can get them with `input()`, for example), you can iterate and accumulate them.

```
price = 0
for movie_number in movie_numbers:
    if movie_number not in Filme:
        continue  # ignore invalid movie numbers

    price += Filme[movie_number].get('Preis', 0)  # price is 0 when no Preis is present

return price
```